# Can't connect to MySQL server error (61)

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I use Sequel Pro as a remote MySQL client. Today I tried to connect to my server with these settings:

[image]

I get this error message when I click connect:

[image]

I don't understand how only a few days ago when I tried to connect it worked with the same settings.

Comment: Is mysql runing and allow conections from remote ips ? ( bind adress )

Comment: @Skamasle Yes it is.

Comment: Does it say "skip-networking" in your my.cnf? Does DNS resolve correctly? Are there firewall rules on the server?

Comment: And from local host can you conect ? if yes maybe is a server firewall blocking conections to 3306 port or skip-networking option like say Ben Lutgens

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure that the DB allows remote connections as well. Check the permissions on the users and databases.

This is an example:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.1.%'
    IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some_characters'  
    WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that MySQL is either stopped, isn't bound to port 3306, or that a firewall is blocking the connection. Do you have shell access to the server? Log in to the server and make sure mysqld is running. Then check whether port 3306 is accepting connections. Then check local and external firewalls to make sure they're allowing inbound 3306.